# How to safely write multiple files at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to write multiple audio files from URL at once in node.js.

Here's a code that seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is a safe way to do it since there are many asynchronous callbacks in a for loop.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

function writeAudioFilesFromUrls(urls) {
  var len = urls.length;
  var files = Array(len).fill();
  var count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    files[i] = fs.createWriteStream(`output/audio${i}.mp3`);
    http.get(urls[i], function (res) {
      res.pipe(files[i]);
      files[i].on('finish', function () {
        files[i].close(function () {
          if (++count == len) {
            console.log("All files are sucessfully written!");
          }
        });
      });
    }); 
  }
}
writeAudioFilesFromUrls(["http://s5.qhres.com/static/465f1f953f1e6ff2.mp3", "http://s5.qhres.com/static/465f1f953f1e6ff2.mp3"]);
```

Is this safe to use this code? If not, how can I fix it?

ADDED: Or is it possible to just make the function work synchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe, you generally want to worry when you attempt to write multiple streams (or whatever) to *the same* file.

You could use `fs.writeFileSync` to get peace of mind but that will most likely slow down your program *and* block your process which may be something you don't want to do depending on your use case.